# create dict keys depending on the number of times the same value occurs

Tags: python

I have a dict as below, if the same value is found more tahn once then the dict key must be created with incremental numbering.

```
TT = {
                "TYPE_1" : ['ERROR'],
                "TYPE_2": ['FATAL'],
                "TYPE_3"  : ["TIME_OUT"],
                "TYPE_4" : ['SYNTAX'],
                "TYPE_5" : ['COMPILE'],
        
  }

  m1 = "ERROR the input is not proper"
  m2 = "This should have not occured FATAL"
  m3 = "Sorry TIME_OUT"
  m4 = "SYNTAX not proper"
  m5 = "u r late its TIME_OUT"
```

The value "TIME_OUT" occur twice in the search.

```
  count = 0
  for key in TT.keys():
    print(key)
    Key_1 = key
    
    while key_1 in TT:
      count = count+1
      key_1 = key + "_{}".format(count)
```

The above code gives error Key_1 not defined.

**Expected OUTPUT:**

if the same value is occuring more than once then the dict key should be created with incremental numbering  "TYPE_3_1" : ["TIME_OUT"],

```
 TT = {
               "TYPE_1" : ['ERROR'],
               "TYPE_2": ['FATAL'],
               "TYPE_3"  : ["TIME_OUT"],
               "TYPE_3_1" : ["TIME_OUT"],
               "TYPE_4" : ['SYNTAX'],
               "TYPE_5" : ['COMPILE'],
       
 }
```

Please suggest on this.

Comment: Sounds like you need to learn about lists and counters

Comment: Adding to the previous comment, I'll mention that the Key_1 not being defined is due to it being case sensitive. When you define Key_1 you're using capitals and later on you name it key_1 which would be a completely different variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There can be a much efficient way of solving this if you can rethink about some of the data structure but if that is not an option you may be able to try this.

```
inputs = ["ERROR the input is not proper", 
"This should have not occured FATAL",
"Sorry TIME_OUT",
"SYNTAX not proper",
"u r late its TIME_OUT"]


basic_types = {
                "TYPE_1" : ['ERROR'],
                "TYPE_2": ['FATAL'],
                "TYPE_3"  : ["TIME_OUT"],
                "TYPE_4" : ['SYNTAX'],
                "TYPE_5" : ['COMPILE'],
        }

type_counts = {}
results = {}

for sentence in inputs:
    for basic_type in basic_types:
        if basic_types.get(basic_type)[0] in sentence:
            type_counts[basic_type] = type_counts.get(basic_type, 0) + 1
            
            if type_counts[basic_type] == 1:
                results[basic_type] = [basic_types.get(basic_type)[0]]
            else:
                results[basic_type+"_{}".format(type_counts[basic_type] - 1)] = [basic_types.get(basic_type)[0]]



print(results)
```